# inparaenum in figure captions

Tags: lists, captions, paralist

Is there a reason why I find it hard to put inline lists in figure captions?

I've defined this:

```
\newcommand{\inlinelist}[1]{\begin{inparaenum}[(a)] #1 \end{inparaenum}}
```

But I can't see anything wrong with it. It only seems to be a problem in captions.

Comment: Most probably you are not protecting `\inlinelist` and probably other commands. However, I would like to see a full minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there's nothing wrong *per se* with you're trying to do. The thing that's tripping you up, though, is that the argument of the `\caption` command can't have what LaTeX calls "moving" or "moving" parts. To make fragile commands "robust," one can prefix them with a `\protect` command.

A separate comment: If there's a chance that you'll need to create a "list of figures" (which can be accomplished with the `\listoffigures` command), you should provide a "short" version of the caption text in the optional argument of the `\caption` command. Otherwise, you'll get more cryptic error messages, this time of the form `Argument of \@caption has an extra }`. The way to get around that is to create a short version of the caption without any "moving" commands at all, as the following MWE shows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\inlinelist}[1]{\begin{inparaenum}[(a)] #1 \end{inparaenum}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption[Hello and Goodbye]% 
   {\inlinelist{%
     \protect\item Hello. 
     \protect\item Goodbye.}%
   }
\centering
\includegraphics{hello.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the OP is using `\item`s in the argument of `\inlinelist`, then `\item`s will also have to be `\protect`ed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- good point. I'll be sure to mention this in an addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Mico Addendum? I think it should be in a footnote:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: footnote or addendum? I've decided to bypass this deep issue by rewriting my answer entirely (now with more information on how to make the caption suitable for processing by the `\listofigures` command...

Comment: @Mico Good answers both in the main post and in the comments:)

Answer (score 4):

You give only fragments of the information needed to answer the question. But the problem seems to be you're dealing with a lot of fragile commands in a moving argument. Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\inlinelist}[1]{\begin{inparaenum}[(a)] #1 \end{inparaenum}}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{\inlinelist{\protect\item foo\protect\item bar}}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```